# Best solution for converting reactjs project based on boilerplate to SSR

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

salam;
We developed a PWA based on react-boilerplate. it's totally based on webpack.
now I'm supposed to implement SSR on this application. the problem is that , I can't find any suitable solution on converting current project to SSR.
I tried nextjs but integration with project is not possible. additionally its requirement for changing infrastructure is too much. 
I tried some other libraries such as react-snapshot and ... but each of them has some specific issues.
any body can help me?

Comment: I did such a migration of 2y'o CRA, I thught it wasn't possible at the beginning, ofcourse it took a lot of time and effort, but if you think -just like I did at the beginning of it- that it's not possible doing that migration with Next.js, then you'll not be able to find a better solution, go fot it, maybe start with creating a Next.js App with a config that suits you application and go from there, I can tell some tips and things to avoid, just reach me out!

Comment: @SultanH.finally last night I made a decision to start with nextjs boilerplate and migrate my project to new one

Comment: Good choice, I will be happy to give tips, but ofcourse, it'll be greater if you run through troubles and make the effort of facing them yourself :+1: